# Efficiently deleting rows in many large text files

Tags: java, .netlink

I have 500 text files each of about 200000 rows. I need to delete one row in each of them as fast as possible (later such operations will repeat). What is the best way to do this with Mathematica?

Solutions using `NETLink`, `JLink` etc. are welcome!

**Update:**

I have found a solution for C#: "[Efficient way to delete a line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/532217/590388)" but I don't know how to adapt it for using through `NETLink`. Another option probably is to use the `java.io.RandomAccessFile` class in Java but I am not very familiar with Java and `JLink`. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Personally I think going with unix command line tools in this case will save you some pain. But you can call them from mma... Even if your on windows (like me) you can still get `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and the like.

Comment: @Ajasja Please provide an example of use of them under Windows.

Comment: 3 years ago, I have written a virtual file system in Java, which uses a single file as a back-end storage, and supports (sub-classes and provides own implementations of) Java InputStream, OutputStream and RandomAccessFile classes (which  should be enough for any practical work). This file system was specifically designed to have fast insert/collapse operations for files, without a full file rewrite, and works orders of magnitude faster than the standard file system, for such operations. It has defragmentation utility, and is very customizable.

Comment: I just ran the unit tests and it works fine (I used a lot of stress testing at the time I wrote it). If you are interested, and would consider first copying your files into it (one-time operation), and then working with it, I can make  a jar out of it, post a link to it, and provide some examples of use, hopefully later today or tomorrow. Of course, using it from Mathematica would involve JLink. The Java code itself is well-documented.

Comment: @Leonid I am interested, but I am not very familiar with Java. If you provide ready-to-use code for simple operations (get `n`'th line in the file(s), get lines fron `n` to `k`, delete `n`'th line, append line to file) it would be very helpful. And what is about fragmentation of the storage file itself?

Comment: I will provide pure Mathematica interface, you won't need to use any Java. As the internal files get fragmented, the storage file grows, and internal defragmentation serves to compress not fully used clusters, and delete the resulting unused ones, effectively reducing the size of the storage file. I have my own cluster system (abstraction), which has nothing to do with the physical clusters, and has special properties, which make it possible to perform fast collapse / insert - so it is completely independent from the way the storage file is physically stored in the file system.

Comment: The only possible problem (not much of a problem, but...) is that my read/write operations work on byte level. So, some extra Java code may be needed to efficiently support the "line"-related abstractions - basically, just finding the byte offset for n-th line, shouldn't be a big deal to add, I will look into it.

Comment: @Leonid I meant the fragmentation of the storage file on the physical drive.

Comment: That's what I also meant. The storage file is a single physical file, which just grows with time, as more virtual files are added, and/or get (virtually) fragmented, or shrinks, when the virtual defrag utility is run (the user controls it). Its own possible *physical* fragmentation is controlled by the real file system. It should not generally be an issue, but if it is, you can run the standard defrag utility on your file system. In any case, this physical fragmentation is not something I'd expect to have any significant effect on things, since it is not moved around a lot.

Comment: @Leonid What is about protection from data loss in the virtual filesystem? I mean if a system failure happens or *Mathematica* or Java will be terminated during writing to a file? Will be the storage file damaged? Is it possible to recover data?

Comment: @Alexey I did not implement extra safety features. There is a chance that the storage will be damaged, and while partial or full recovery might be possible in principle, I did not implement the tools for that. One very easy thing to do is to set a periodical task that would simply back up the storage file periodically - this can be even done externally. More elaborate schemes are possible, but they would require more work (for example, the most vulnerable part is FAT table, and  I could store a second reserved copy of it - like it is done in real file systems - and use that for recovery).

Comment: I have to agree with @Ajasja: Mathematica is not the best tool for this.  I usually use other tools for this (`awk`, `python`, etc.), and integrate them with Mathematica if necessary (e.g. through pipes).  What condition do you use to remove the line?  (Line number, some mathematical computation on the contents, just matching a string in the contents, etc.?)

Comment: @Szabolcs Line number. I get it through some complex analysis on the contents of files but the most slow part is deleting the line. It would be perfect if I could delete the line without loading/rewriting entire files.

Comment: @Alexey Just a suggestion (not an answer to the question):  if you need to do this many times, repeatedly, you could instead keep track of which lines "are present" or "are missing" from the file, and store this information elsewhere.  This will be much faster than rewriting a big file.  Then occasionally you can "compact" the file by actually removing those lines that are not needed in a single go, and updating the associated information to make sure it's consistent.

Answer (score 5):

If you'll accept solutions involving other technologies, then how about using `sed`? On a unix system, to read in `file1`, delete row `n` and output to `file2`, you'd do:

```
sed -e 'nd' file1 > file2
```

The quotes in `'nd'` are not necessary in this case, since there is only one instruction. However, if you're doing more complicated stuff with regular expressions, you should include the quotes so that the regex is not interpreted as something else. So it's safer to include it in general.

If you want to edit the file in place, then the command is

```
sed -i '' -e 'nd' test
```

Note that the `''`after `-i` is necessary if you don't want a backup. If you omit that then `sed` assumes that the extension is being supplied via stdin, introducing additional files (which really are backups).

If you want to backup your file, just in case, then use `-i.abc` where `abc` is any string of your choice (need not be limited to 3 chars) and the file will be backed up to `file.abc`.

You can now run any of these commands from Mathematica via `Run[command]` (where `command` is the string with the actual command). Of course, replace `n` above with your actual row number or if variable, modify `Run[...]` accordingly.

---

I don't use Windows, but [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) should provide you with a linux environment for Windows.

If you only require `sed` then cygwin is an overkill (takes a lot of space and is quite slow). A native build of `sed` can be found as part of [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). Download [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Comment: Is it possible to modify the original file without reading/writing it entirely? I noticed that (for example) EmEditor saves a file with manually deleted row extremely fast (probably by modifying only a part of it on the disk). Are there any command-line tools with such a possibility?

Comment: Also, sed has an inplace option if I remember correctly. But then the Q&A should be migrated to another stackexchange...

Comment: @Ajasja I added the in-place option. I don't think this should be migrated, because sometimes, the answer to how do I do X in mathematica is "Don't use Mathematica" :)

Comment: @R.M I just have downloaded [sed 4.2.1](http://ignum.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/sed/4.2.1/sed-4.2.1-setup.exe) and found that the correct syntax is `sed -i -e nd test` (without `''`).

Comment: @R.M It seems that I have found a bug in MMa: evaluation `Import["!sed -i -e nd test","String"]` (with `n` replaced with an integer and `test` is a TXT-file) leads to creation a file with name like "sed3dcXyy" in the `Directory[]` (may be changed via `SetDirectory`). The file is not removed after finishing evaluation. It seems that this file is a copy of the `test` file. (Currently I use MMa 7.0.1.)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It is not a bug. Please see my edit — Ι should've made this clearer.

Comment: If no output is expected, would not be `Run` better?

Comment: @FJRA You're right. I'm used to accessing the shell from inside mma solely to get the output that I used the same. Please feel free to edit that sentence to add `Run`

Comment: @R.M `sed -i '' -e nd test` also creates the backup file on my system and gives error message: "sed.exe: cannot be read '': No such file or directory".

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Hmm... strange. I'm surprised it does that because these tools are generally written such that they're portable between OSes. I don't have windows to actually try it out, but I'll try looking through GNUWin's manual to see if it has something about it

Comment: @R.M It looks like a bug in `sed`: according to "Usage" message, "-i[SUFFIX], -in-place[=SUFFIX] edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)" and so `-i` should be sufficient. As of `'` symbols, on Windows they probably should be replaced with `"` according to notes on the "[GnuWin: Installation and Usage](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html)" page (section "Filename globbing and quoted arguments").

Comment: @R.M It is definitely a bug: even if I supply an extension (for example, `i.bak`) the file with name like "sedhTxVjV" is created alongside with the .bak-file! And this file is not a backup copy: it is identical to the target (new) file!

Comment: Check out Gow (https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) for some unix tools compiled natively on windows without cygwin.

Comment: @s0rce Thank you for the link, but it has a rather old version of `sed` that does not support the `-i` (or `--in-place`) option.