# How to remove an expression from a file?

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

To read in expressions from a file, one can do `ReadList[file, Expression, 3]`.  How to do the opposite, i.e. remove a number of expressions from a file, modifying the file on the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Functions like Read, Skip and Find usually operate on streams in an
>   entirely sequential fashion. Each time one of the functions is called,
>   the current point in the stream moves on.

In a Sequential file you can´t *delete* entries. The only option is shifting the "tail" of the file upwards.

[image]

Comment: What does "shifting the 'tail' of the file upwards" mean?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika Please see figure

Comment: How do you "shift the 'tail' of the file upwards" by a Mathematica program?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika I guess the easiest way is to copy (replicate) the whole file without the "deleted" elements. If the file is too big for that, _perhaps_ there are other ways. Let us know

Comment: If I always know where the expression I want to delete is in the file, is the best approach reading in the whole file (`ReadList[file, Expression]`), deleting the expression in memory (`Drop[list, 4]`), then rewriting the resultant expression back into file (`Write[...]`)?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika That is the most direct approach, yes. You could also truncate the file (by issuing an appropriate OS call) and then append the tail of the file via Mma.

Comment: If you do a buffered read, it is possible to delete a number of elements up to the size of the buffer. The process could be repeated to delete multiple non-contiguous blocks.

Comment: @MaThEmAtika There was a [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/efficiently-deleting-rows-in-many-large-txt-files) recently, where in the comments I described another possibility, based on a virtual file system (VFS) I once wrote (in Java). I am currently working on its Mathematica bindings, and hope to make it available soon. My VFS was specially designed for fast removal and insertion of buffers into files without full rewrites. One thing though, it works on a byte level, so to use it most effectively, one needs to know the byte positions of things in a file.

Answer (score 1):

A filtered stream reading function:

```
Clear[MakeFilteredReader];
Options[MakeFilteredReader] = {Omit -> None};
MakeFilteredReader[stream_InputStream, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{omitList = OptionValue@Omit, position = 0},
  Function[s, position += 1;
   If[MemberQ[omitList, position],
    Skip[stream, s];,
    Read[stream, s]]
   ]
  ]
```

Define a stream to read.

```
str = StringToStream["103 123456 234 456 34"];
```

Create a reader on that stream.

```
fr = MakeFilteredReader[str, Omit -> {2, 3}];
```

Read from the filtered stream reader.

```
{fr[Number], fr[Number], fr[Number], fr[Number], fr[Number],  fr[Number]}
```

Which returns:

```
{103, Null, Null, 456, 34, EndOfFile}
```

Comment: My goal is to have the file modified such that expressions at certain indices are removed, not actually selectively reading expressions from file into memory.  But as I said earlier, one can read expressions into memory, alter it, and rewrite the whole file.  The main thing I am seeking optimization for is to somehow avoid rewriting much of the unchanged expressions back into file.

Comment: I.e. I'd like to find ways to avoid the trip to memory for the expressions that won't need change/deletetion.

Comment: @MaThEmAtika Doesn't preventing the read into memory (I'm not sure if you can easily avoid the low level buffered read that may lurk beneath Mathematica, maybe someone knows if `Skip` drops it's input before committing to Mathematica's managed memory ) require that you know beforehand the structure of the file? I'm not sure that this meta data on structure is available.

Comment: We can make one assumption about the file's data structure that the file contain a sequence of mathematica expressions, separated by newline character.  And I know I want to remove the $n^{th}$ expression, for example.

Comment: Would preprocessing the file to add/encapsulate meta date about the structure be possible ?

Comment: Could you concretize "meta data" a little?  What information should it has, for my desired goal, i.e. find ways to avoid the trip to memory for the expressions that won't need change/deletetion?

Comment: If I understand you correctly,  it's definitely possible to compute size, some kind of index, and some representation of the data structure of the data, and write that metadata along with the content data to file.  Do you have suggestions?

Comment: As a caution, you should close the stream, as it can go [badly](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion) if you don't. And, yes I have personal experience with my computer grinding to a halt because of this.

Comment: I'd be interested in simply being able to overwrite binary values in a file, ala matlab or idl open in read-write mode. Basically a SetStreamPosition[] on a file I can write to.